# ASP.NET if web form navigated change <a> class

Tags: asp.net, html, class

How i can handler if web for navigated and then change anchor tag class?

Comment: You might want to rephrase this slightly. Try and example, it might help.

Comment: I have no idea what your question means. Please spend more time deciding how to pose it more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a:visited
{
    color:red;
}
```

Who knows what you meant...